# What kind of fish (will you use/are you using/do you use)?

Tags: present-tense, future-tense, present-continuous

If I see my friend preparing her/his fish for cooking, and I wonder what kind of fish it is, what is the suitable sentence to ask her/him?

> (a) What kind of fish **will you use**?
>
> (b) What kind of fish **are you using**?
>
> (c) What kind of fish **do you use**?

...etc

Is there anything wrong if I use the present simple tense
because I just want to know the general information?

I am afraid of overusing the continuous tense in speaking.

Comment: What fish is that?

Answer (score 1):

As you see the fish being prepared: 'What kind of fish are you using?' Or 'What kind of fish is that?'

The present continuous tense is most often used for actions happening now. It fits your scenario nicely.

http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/prescont.htm

Comment: Future (“will”) is inappropriate because you already see that your friend is using a fish. “Do” is also inappropriate because that implies “on a regular basis”, not *now* in particular.